# Alternative to multiple padarray calls to get a perimeter mask for image

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I have an array of doubles `img` which I use to multiple with a mask `mask.*img` where the mask will have values of 1 in the middle but go linearly to 0 at the borders e.g. for a 5x5 mask it would be something like

```
0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.1
0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1 
0.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.1
0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

My idea for this currently is to create the center using `x = ones(M)`
and then create a sequence of decreasing values `y = [0.9 0.5 0.3 0.1]`
and then do

```
for k = 1: size(y)
   x = padarray(x,[1 1], y(k))
```

which will add the values of y as a perimeter around x multiple times, one at a time. Is there a more clever way to create this kind of mask that tapers off at the perimeter?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting way to do something similar might be. Where vector `Taper` is the same as the centre row of the 5 by 5 matrix. The rows are generated by comparing the corresponding element in the transpose with the vector `Taper` which is `Taper.'`.

### Broken down into steps:

Row 1: `min([0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1],[0.1]);` → `[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1]` 
Row 2: `min([0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1],[0.5]);` → `[0.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.1]` 
Row 3: `min([0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1],[1]);`     → `[0.1 0.5  1  0.5 0.1]` 
Row 4: `min([0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1],[0.5]);` → `[0.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.1]` 
Row 5: `min([0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1],[0.1]);` → `[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1]`

```
Taper = [0.1 0.5 1 0.5 0.1];
Result = min(Taper, Taper.');

Result
```

[image: Output Result]

Comment: Interesting idea. How would you extend this to the non-symmetric case where you have more rows than columns or vice-versa?

Comment: No clue, it would depend on how you would like the taper to be configured.

Comment: Ideally, I would want a ring like pattern where the outermost row and column are filled with one value, then a ring inside that with a bigger value etc.

Comment: There will be the case where a ring has to have two sides with a larger thickness when the dimensions are not equal though.